# Use non-english characters in List.js

Tags: javascript, regex, special-characters, listjs

I have a list of features created with List.js library. Is there any way I could match non-english characters with regular ones?
For example, the list contains this elements: 'șuncă', 'brânză', 'mărar'.
I'm curious if there's a way to find these elements even if I'm searching without the non-english characters, like this: 'sunca', 'branza', 'marar'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`filter()` API function](http://www.listjs.com/docs/list-api) and a helper function to replace accented characters in a string with their base versions.

Helper functions

```
// generic accent removal from input string, add any missing characters
var removeAccents = (function () {
    var letters1 = "äáàâăëéèêĕüúùûŭöóòôŏÄÁÀÂĂËÉÈÊĔÜÚÙÛŬÖÓÒÔŎßșȘ",
        letters2 = "aaaaaeeeeeuuuuuoooooAAAAAEEEEEUUUUUOOOOOssS",
        patternLetters = new RegExp("[" + letters1 + "]", "g"),
        lookupLetters = {}, letterTranslator;

    letters1.split("").forEach(function (letter, i) {
        lookupLetters[letter] = letters2[i];
    });

    letterTranslator = function(match) { 
        return lookupLetters[match] || match;
    };

    return function removeAccents(input) {
        return input.replace(patternLetters, letterTranslator);
    };
})();

// creates a specific filter function for use in List.js
function getAccentInsensitiveFilter(property, search) {
    search = removeAccents(search).toLowerCase();

    return function (item) {
        var value = removeAccents(item.values()[property] || "").toLowerCase();
        return value.indexOf(search) > -1;
    };
}
```

and then

```
// filter for "sunca" in the "featureName" property
yourList.filter(getAccentInsensitiveFilter("featureName", "șuncă"));

// remove filter 
yourList.filter();
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I've never worked before with regex expressions, and I'm also new to List.js. Given the code from this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/FEs04jxVNdTjiIerYUX4 , can you tell me how can I implement that filter? The list is created at line 51 in script.js, and I'm searching through meniu.geojson properties

Comment: Uhh, no, I'm not going to debug/write your application for you. I suggest you go through the API documentation and work your way from the examples in the docs to small, self-contained test cases, to your bigger web application, step by step. Understand how the List.js API works first. Write a much simpler filter function yourself and apply it to your list. Understand `getAccentInsensitiveFilter()`. You don't have to fully understand `removeAccents()` for now, just test how it reacts. I'm sorry, but I'm afraid you will have to work your own way through.